# jquery scroll bar not works in dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, tinyscrollbar

Kindly guide me what i am missing, i was trying different things but it stuck,

i made a dropdrown notification and want to use jquery scroll bar in it to make it cool, but i have tried many jquery plugin but the thing is all are stop working when try to call them in the element which comes in hover.

Finally i go with *tiny scroll bar* but it also show me disable for the class in which it generate scroll bar,

i have been checked there is no jquery error.

below is my link in which i work, appreciate any help

http://techchef.org/numoni/dashboard.html

Comment: your question isn't clear; where is the dropdown notification? do you want to add the scrolbar to the items in the accordian?

Comment: my friend at the top right there are two icons, so if u hover on the first one you will get the div visble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have done that:)
the thing is scroll bar doesnot works, if the element is by default set to none, as it calculates the element height & width, show i use toggle function for this instead of display:none, i use visibility as hidden by default.

so i do like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#notificationicon").click(function(){
  $("#notificationdropdown").slideDown("slow");
   $("#notificationdropdown").attr("style", "visibility: visible");
});

$("#notificationdropdown").mouseleave(function(){
$("#notificationdropdown").slideUp("slow");
});
```